# Matplotlib imshow figure size is too small

Tags: python, matplotlib

The following code

```
from life import Life
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

dim_row = 20
dim_col = 20
data = [ [ 0 * dim_col for i in range(dim_col)] * dim_row for j in range(dim_row) ]
from random import randint
for i in range(dim_row):
    for j in range(dim_col):
        data[i][j] = randint(0,1)

# print(data)

life = Life(initial=data)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.imshow(life._initial)

for i in range(100):
    ax.cla()
    ax.imshow(life.next_generation())
    ax.adjustable='datalim'
    ax.share=True
```

Generates the following image

[image: Figure Output]

I want to fix the image - to make it clear. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: just a tip: `data = np.random.randint(0, 1, size=(20, 20))`

Comment: question: did you intend to have a 20 x 20 image, or a 20 x 400 image?

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Really useful.
About the size, I intend to have 20 x 20 image, but the attached one is the one I get.

Comment: By the way, I don't want it to be as small as it is displayed in the image. I want it to be large and clear.

Comment: Well, you fed matplotlib a 20x400 image, hence the shape. Feed it a 20x20 image and it'll scale up better.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. If you kindly tell me how to do this, it would be great.

Comment: My very first comment generates a 20x20 array